# Zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ imply $n$ is not a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My teachers' proof says: if $\exists\ a,b>1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ab=0\bmod n$, then $ab=nk$ for some integer $k$ and hence $n$ is not a prime. Please explain the last conclusion. (It would have been trivial if we knew that $ab|n$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that since $ab = nk$, we have $n \mid ab$. But if $n$ were a prime, then this would imply either $n\mid a$ or $n \mid b$. Since we've excluded either of those, we can conclude that $n$ cannot be prime.